# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

I'm trying compile using `mvn install` but I'm getting this error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.0.2:compile (default-compile) on project test: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:

pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
  <artifactId>test</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>test</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <descriptorRefs>
          <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
        <archive>
          <manifest>
            <mainClass>com.mycompany.test.App</mainClass>
          </manifest>
        </archive>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.25</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

How to fix it?

Comment: `Compilation failure: Compilation failure:`. This is your hint.

Comment: Its a compile failure.  Means your java code wont compile.

Comment: @Lucas In netbeans I successfully compile my code

Comment: Check if you have added necessary dependencies

Comment: If netbeans compiles it, then it is most likely the scope of your dependencies.  The IDE will provide all scopes in its build path so even your test/provided dependencies will show, but when compiling with maven, only compile dependencies are available.

Comment: @Chris I added dependencies. Netbeans compile my code

Comment: @Lucas I thinked, that maven must download all dependencies from repo. And it did this. But some time later maven can't compile project. Maybe it's system error? I'm using Linux.

Comment: @rustock, Maven did download the dependencies.  You should be able to find them in `~/.m2/repository/...`.  However, downloading them, and having them in your classpath are 2 different things.  You can run `mvn -X package` to get the details of that maven is actually doing, but when you run a maven build, it only adds the `compile` scoped jars (and their transitive dependencies) to the classpath of the `javac` command.  Hence, even though you have the jar in your local repository, it is not necessarily in the classpath for the compile command.

Comment: @Lucas I moved the class, which was recently added and maven working. What is was? This class contain some buttons and text field and is not called anywhere. why it influenced to work of maven?

Comment: No idea, not nearly enough information to answer that question

Comment: @Lucas I understand, all class must be linked otherwise maven can't compile project. I't my error. I forgot about it. Big thanks for help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your issue is most likely the `<scope>` of the dependency.  When inside of the IDE, all scopes are added to the build path of the project.  However, when running `mvn` only the appropriate scopes are added to the classpath for the `javac` command.  For example, if you had a class in `/src/main/java` that imported a class from one of your dependencies scoped to `<scope>test</scope>`, the IDE would be able to build the project, but `mvn` would fail in the manner you are experiencing.

Comment: then what should be done in this case ? My project has suddenly stopped building given this as reason.

Comment: @rai.skumar Use proper scopes for your dependencies.  You could just use `<scope>compile</scope>` for everything, which should let it compile, but that is a _VERY_ poor design.  Better to just read the [documentation](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope) on what the scopes mean and determine which changes you need to make.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar error when trying to download and compile the aws kinesis consumer library (kcl)

```
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.0.2:compile (default-compile) @ amazon-kinesis-client ---
[INFO] Compiling 81 source files to /opt/speedshiftmedia/aws.kcl/1.1.0/target/classes
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.822s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Jul 22 12:31:39 PDT 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 4M/56M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.0.2:compile (default-compile) on project amazon-kinesis-client: Compilation failure
[ERROR] Failure executing javac, but could not parse the error:
[ERROR] javac: invalid target release: 1.7
```

It turns out that while I had updated my version of Java from 1.6 to 1.7, I had not updated Javac from 1.6 to 1.7.

To do so I used the following command on ubuntu

```
sudo update-alternatives --config javac
```

And then choose the desired version at the prompt.

```
There are 2 choices for the alternative javac (providing /usr/bin/javac).



Selection    Path                                         Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac   1061      auto mode
   1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac   1061      manual mode
   2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac   1051      manual mode

Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

I hope this helps someone else.